# Using allocate statements instead of type statements (?!)

Tags: fortran

So I'm fixing up and adding to some legacy code (it's either free-form Fortran 77 or Fortran 90, not sure entirely what the differences are). I came across something very bizarre, which thankfully doesn't compile with the Intel Fortran compiler, but apparently has compiled in our codebase for ages.

```
SUBROUTINE TAKESTEPAMBER(JP,y,movableatomlist,nmovableatoms,ligmovet,mdstept1,randomseedt2,blockmovet,nblocks,atomsinblock)
use modamber9
use commons, only : natoms, change_temp, newres_temp
use nblist, only : nbflag, skinnb
use porfuncs

implicit none


integer JP, itime1, now(3), nmovableatoms,i,j,movableatomlist(nmovableatoms),nblocks,atomsinblock(nblocks),offset1,k
allocate(y(3*natoms), grad(3*natoms), ereal,ligandcentre(3),ligandcoords(3),ligandcoordsrotated(3))
allocate(rotationmatrix(nblocks,3,3),twopi,pi,DPRAND,randomphi,randompsi,randomtheta,DIST, dummyz)
allocate(st,ct,sph,cph,sps,cps, VECBAX, VECBAY, VECBAZ, randomx, randomy, randomz, dummyx, dummyy)
allocate(atomblockcentre(nblocks,3),distancematrix(natoms,natoms))
allocate(ligmovet,mdstept1,randomseedt2,reschangedt(nres),blockmovet,overlapt)
allocate(datechar,timechar,zonechar)
allocate(values(8),iostatus,restemp,i1,currentresidue,resnumber,overlaparray(natoms,natoms))
allocate(overlaparraysave(natoms,natoms))
allocate(rotmaxchangestr,rotpselectstr,rotcutoffstr,rotcentrestr,rotoccuwstr)

<...execution stuff using all of those variables up there...>

END SUBROUTINE TAKESTEPAMBER
```

My question is whether anyone has any idea what's going on and how this might work. The variables are all sorts of different types and I don't know how the compiler would be able to work this out.

Would it be able to take the type specification from the various included module files?

And yes, don't worry, we know it's awful, I just thought that somebody might be able to explain this particular bit of weirdness. It's not a problem, per se, since I'm going to replace everything with appropriate type specifications.

Thanks,

Kyle

Comment: It may be totally OK, we do not see how they are declared in their modules.

Comment: Maybe it is even Fortran 2003 with allocatable scalars.

Comment: A good number of these things aren't declared anywhere. For example, datechar, timechar and zonechar are the arguments passed to call date_and_time(datechar, timechar, zonechar, values)

Comment: Can't they be in `modamber9` or `porfuncs`?

Comment: I looked, they're not there.

Comment: Then it is completely weird.

Comment: I note that y is a dummy argument, so it has to be declared locally. As presented, this code is simply illegal. I wonder if "allocate" is a preprocessor macro rather than the Fortran ALLOCATE statement.

Comment: I'll check that out. It was more a case of curiosity more than anything. I know how to clean it up nicely, it's just a bit tedious.